# Find white space between end of word and equal sign

Tags: regex

I have of word documents filled with this type of lines

1. ```
   word  = home
   ```
2. ```
   fig       = tree
   ```
3. ```
   car                  = yatch
   ```

I want to select the white space between the end of the first word and the = sign. There is a search and replace feature in word but I can't figure out the regex that will select those spaces. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word? You mean, Microsoft(r) Word(tm)? Maybe this

```
> @=
```

replace with "="

Answer (score 0):

You can try `s/\ +=/=/g` : which means, 1 space or more plus '=' subtitute it by only '='.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `/.+?\w*?=/` should get close for you.